# Perl - Can't locate object method via "Module::SUPER"

Tags: perl, super

This is my first time using OOP with perl. I am in the processes of refactoring a 4k line procedural program at work. It seems pretty straight forward but I am having an issue with inheritance and SUPER.

**Error message:**

```
"Can't locate object method "New" via package "Module::SUPER" at Module.pm line 10"
```

I have tried, use base, parent and setting @ISA but they all get the same error. I'm sure I have to be overlooking something.

(This is not code from the program I am working on. Just an example that produces the same error)

All .pm and .pl files are in the same directory in this example. In the program I am working on the main program is in bin and the modules will be in ../modules(relative to bin). 
I would assume this would be all I need to make that work:

```
use lib "../modules";
```

If I am wrong in thinking that please let me know.

**Parent Module**

```
package BaseModule;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self  = {
        ARRAY => shift,
        DIVIDER => ","
    };
    bless ($self, $class);
    return $self;
}
sub array {
    my $self = shift;
    if(@_) { $self->{ARRAY} = shift };
    return $self->{ARRAY};  
}
sub divider {
    my $self = shift;
    if(@_) { $self->{DIVIDER} = shift };
    return $self->{DIVIDER};    
}
sub testSub {
    my $self = shift;   
    print join($self->{DIVIDER}, @{ $self->{ARRAY} } );
    return 1;
}

1;
```

**Child Module**

```
package Module;
use strict;
use warnings;
#use base qw(BaseModule);
#require BaseModule;
#our @ISA = qw(BaseModule);
use parent qw(BaseModule);
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self  = $class->SUPER::New(@_);
    $self->{STRING} = shift;
    bless ($self, $class);
    return $self;
}
sub string {
    my $self = shift;
    if(@_) { $self->{STRING} = shift };
    return $self->{STRING}; 
}
sub testSub {
    my $self = shift;
    print "$self->{STRING}:\n";
    $self->SUPER::testSub();
    return 1;
}    
1;
```

Do I need to bless the child class if the parent class returns an already blessed $self?

**Main Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Module;

my $module = Module->new([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "Example");
$module->divider(" | "); # Test Changing divider;
$module->testSub();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means @el.pescado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"Can't locate object method "New" via package "Module::SUPER" at Module.pm line 10"
```

You try to call `BaseModule::New` whis hasn't been defined (did you mean `BaseModule::new`? Perl is case sensitive).

> Do I need to bless the child class if the parent class returns an
>   already blessed $self?

No, `$self` at that point is already blesses (you could check that by means of `Scalar::Util::blessed()`.

Comment: Wow. I completely overlooked that. The case was my issue. new vs New. It works now. Thank you very much!